# Measuring the expected energy of a quantum circuit

Tags: circuit-construction, cirq

I implemented the following circuit: [image: irc]

I am interested in measuring the expected energy of the circuit. I am using Cirq. I am wondering what are the next steps. Sorry if the question seems very basic, but I am not sure how to interpret the measurement gate to extract this energy.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Circuits don't have a defined quantity called energy. Do you have a Hamiltonian in mind, and want to measure the energy of the output of the circuit w.r.t. that Hamiltonian?

Comment: That is a great question! First of all, nice to meet you! Second, I just adding the paper for reference https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2018/cmsc657/projects/group_16.pdf

This is actually a big question I have: I am still working on understanding how to take a hamiltonian and develop an ansatz, and in this particular case, how to do the reverse.

Comment: Having (very) briefly skimmed that paper you mentioned, I'd be quite suspicious of the circuit you're trying to implement. It seems that the authors have implicitly assumed that $\sum_nX_n$ and $\sum_nZ_nZ_{n+1}$ commute, which they don't

Comment: @DaftWullie: Thank you for telling me!

Comment: @DaftWullie It's pretty common to see Hamiltonians that decompose into non-commuting terms being simulated via Trotterization. And the particular alternation of X basis and Z basis stuff is particularly common; it shows up in Grover, in the QAOA, etc.

Comment: @CraigGidney Sure, but then there’s a condition on the steps being small, and repeated, neither of which seem to be true in this specific case.

Comment: I got a question: suppose I add a 4-bit Toffoli gate in the fifth qubit below, and then acted a Y gate and then measure. Why this method has turn unsuccessful to optimize the parameters of the circuit in question ?